# Swift iOS -Remove View When TextField, TextView, and Background Tapped But Losing Events

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

[image]  [image]

First let me say I play around with programmatic but I'm currently a novice at it.

I have mix of programmatic views and storyboard objects:

StoryBoard Objects:

1. Button
2. TextField
3. TextView

Programmatic Views:

1. messageLabel
2. viewForMessageLabel

When I press the button the `viewForMessageLabel` is added. In `viewDidLoad` I add a tap gesture to remove the `viewForMessageLabel` when the background is tapped. I also add the same tap gesture to the textField to remove the `viewForMessageLabel` if it's present. I again add the same tap gesture to the textField to remove it also.

If the keyboard is present I add another tap gesture to in `viewDidLoad` to the textField to dismiss it also. I notice things are wacky and I lose touch events.

If I press the button to add the label when I touch the background it doesn't get dismissed. If I press the textField it will dismiss it and show the keyboard. While the textField is still up if I press the button again, the label appears, I press the textField again and nothing happens. When I press return to hide the keyboard (I implemented the method), the keyboard disappears, press the button, the `viewForMessageLabel` appears, and I now when I press the textField the `viewForMessageLabel` disappears. Basically the same thing is happening with the textField.

What I want is

1. If the `viewForMessageLabel` is present and I press either the background, textField, or textView it should disappear.
2. If the textField's or textView's keyboard is present and I press the background the keyboard should disappear also.

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    //MARK:- Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    let messagelabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Pizza Pizza Pizza Pizza Pizza"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Regular", size: 17)
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return label
    }()

    let viewForMessageLabel: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return view
    }()

    //View Controller Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
        textView.delegate = self

        // 0. hide viewForMessageLabel is background is tapped
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeViewForMessageLabel))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        // 1. hide viewForMessageLabel if textView is tapped
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        // 2. hide keyboard if background if tapped
        let hideKeyboard = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboardWhenBackGroundTapped))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboard)

        // 3. hide keyboard if textView is tapped
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboard)

        // 4. hide viewForMessageLabel for textField if background is tapped
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeViewForMessageLabel), for: .editingDidBegin)

    }

    //MARK:- Button
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        view.addSubview(viewForMessageLabel)
        setViewForMessageLabelAnchors()
        setMessageLabelAnchors()
    }

    //MARK:- Functions
    func setViewForMessageLabelAnchors(){
        viewForMessageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 44).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.addSubview(messagelabel)
    }

    func setMessageLabelAnchors(){
        messagelabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForMessageLabel.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        messagelabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForMessageLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messagelabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    func removeViewForMessageLabel(){
        viewForMessageLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func hideKeyboardWhenBackGroundTapped(){
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    //MARK:- TextField Delegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        removeViewForMessageLabel()
    }

    //MARK:- TextView Delegate
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of overlapping tap gesture recognizers. I'm not sure taps pass through by default. It kinda seems like you're overcomplicating this.

Comment: @toddg thanks. I just read a post that said I can add another action to the same tap. I'm going to try it. Why did you say I'm over complicating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer the question but I found a work around. If I use the method @Toddg suggested:

```
func removeLabelAndHideKeyboard() {
    viewForMessageLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

It adds resigning the textField to the function which helped tremendously.

Also inside viewDidLoad I added:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeViewForMessageLabel), for: .touchDown)
```

The key there is to use **.touchDown** and NOT .editingDidBegin. This way I can go back and forth in between the textField and the textView and the keyboard will respond to both. I had to add 1 more thing -a toolBar to the textView's keyboard which has Done button on it to dismiss the textView:

```
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(){
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton!], animated: true)
        textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    @objc func dismissTextViewKeyboard(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

This way when the textView is present I can dismiss it.

In all situations if I press the textField, background, or textView and the viewForMessageLabel is present it will disappear.

If the textField is first responder and it's keyboard is present and I press the background it will disappear.

I have not figured out how to also dismiss the textView when the background is touched in addition to everything else so I implemented a Done button on the toolBar instead. If I press it and the textView's keyboard is present will get dismissed when it calls the `dismissTextViewKeyboard()` function I added in. Both are at the bottom and everything else is in viewDidLoad.

If anyone has a better answer I'll up vote it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {


    //MARK:- Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    let messagelabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Pizza Pizza Pizza Pizza Pizza"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Regular", size: 17)
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return label
    }()

    let viewForMessageLabel: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return view
    }()

    fileprivate var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem?

    //View Controller Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.delegate = self
        textView.delegate = self

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeViewForMessageLabel))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeViewForMessageLabel), for: .touchDown)

        addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    }

    //MARK:- Button
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //removeMessage()
        view.addSubview(viewForMessageLabel)
        setBackgroundAnchors()
        setMessageAndLabelAnchors()
    }

    //MARK:- Functions
    func setBackgroundAnchors(){
        viewForMessageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 44).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.addSubview(messagelabel)
    }

    func setMessageAndLabelAnchors(){

        messagelabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForMessageLabel.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        messagelabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewForMessageLabel.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        viewForMessageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messagelabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    func removeViewForMessageLabel(){
        viewForMessageLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    //MARK:- TextField Delegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        removeViewForMessageLabel()
    }

    //MARK:- TextView Delegate
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    //MARK:- Additional Functions
    //add a done button to the keyboard when the textView is first responder
    fileprivate func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard(){
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissTextViewKeyboard))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton!], animated: true)
        textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    //dismiss the keyboard when the Done button is tapped
    @objc func dismissTextViewKeyboard(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> 2. If the textField's or textView's keyboard is present and I press the background the keyboard should disappear also.

You present this like it's conditional on whether the keyboard is currently shown but your code doesn't reflect that (and it shouldn't). You can call `resignFirstResponder` as many times as you want and nothing bad will happen. You can also call `removeFromSuperview` on a view that's already been removed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293948/4228969)).

Thus I think you can just have one action attached to a single tap gesture recognizer:

```
var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.delegate = self
    textView.delegate = self

    // 0. hide viewForMessageLabel is background is tapped
    tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeLabelAndHideKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    // 1. hide viewForMessageLabel if textView is tapped
    textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func removeLabelAndHideKeyboard() {
    viewForMessageLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I'll try it as soon I get home in a couple of hrs 

Comment: Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. First I key the delegate methods in there then i commented them out (then uncommented them). When the keyboard is present and I tap the background nothing happens. When the keyboard and viewForMessageLabel are both present and I tap the bg nothing happens. With both still present I tap the textField and the view is still present. The only thing that removes the view is the textView. I c+p what your wrote and commented out everything else in viewDidLoad too

Comment: I think it might be because a `UITextField` already has gesture recognizers. Now my question is why you would want to hide the keyboard when a user taps on the textfield

Comment: lol your right I over looked that, smh. I was just playing with it. If I use: tapGesture = ... and func removeLabelAndHideKeyboard() {
    viewForMessageLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
} I can tap the background or the textView and the view will disappear. If the textField is chosen and I tap the bg the keyboard will disappear. Now here are the 2 problems: 1. If I tap the textView and touch the background the keyboard stays. 2. If the view is present and I tap the textfield the view doesn't disappear

Comment: I found a work around using a toolBar for the textView and .touchDown of the textField. The additional line you added into the function helped a lot. You was right when you said I overcomplicated it. I'm going to up your answer. Thanks!